# Set Geolocation for Splash browser (Scrapy/Python)

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to set the geolocation of the browser so that when i go to a website, it recognizes my location since the page won't load unless i have the geolocation set. Does anyone know how to set it in the splash-scrapy? I looked around online, but it seems no one has asked this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently Splash doesn't support geolocation; there is an open issue (https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/499), but not any progress (as of July 2017).